# Unable to Change Date Format for Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datepicker, momentjs

Our team currently uses a bootstrap template for our registration page and the datepicker that comes with it.
The datepicker formats a selected date as DD/MM/YYYY. Of course, SQL uses YYYY-MM-DD, so submitting the date with the datepicker's format creates an error.

Apparently the datepicker (created by Dan Grossman) uses Moment.js, and I tried changing the format in its datepicker.js from

```
this.locale = {
            format: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L')
}
```

to

```
this.locale = {
      format: moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}
```

It didn't work. I tried looking for its other js files and found global.js. Changed the date formats indicated in the following from

```
try {
        $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoUpdateInput": false,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            },
        });
    
        var myCalendar = $('.js-datepicker');
        var isClick = 0;
    
        $(window).on('click',function(){
            isClick = 0;
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('apply.daterangepicker',function(ev, picker){
            isClick = 0;
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    
        });
    
        $('.js-btn-calendar').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
    
            if(isClick === 1) isClick = 0;
            else if(isClick === 0) isClick = 1;
    
            if (isClick === 1) {
                myCalendar.focus();
            }
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            isClick = 1;
        });
    
        $('.daterangepicker').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    
    
    } catch(er) {console.log(er);}
    /*[ Select 2 Config ]
        ===========================================================*/
    
    try {
        var selectSimple = $('.js-select-simple');
    
        selectSimple.each(function () {
            var that = $(this);
            var selectBox = that.find('select');
            var selectDropdown = that.find('.select-dropdown');
            selectBox.select2({
                dropdownParent: selectDropdown
            });
        });
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

to

```
 try {
        $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoUpdateInput": false,
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
        });

        var myCalendar = $('.js-datepicker');
        var isClick = 0;

        $(window).on('click',function(){
            isClick = 0;
        });

        $(myCalendar).on('apply.daterangepicker',function(ev, picker){
            isClick = 0;
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        });

        $('.js-btn-calendar').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();

            if(isClick === 1) isClick = 0;
            else if(isClick === 0) isClick = 1;

            if (isClick === 1) {
                myCalendar.focus();
            }
        });

        $(myCalendar).on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            isClick = 1;
        });

        $('.daterangepicker').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });


    } catch(er) {console.log(er);}
```

Nothing changes.
I am still very new to JavaScript and I have no idea what to do. What other solutions can I try?

UPDATE: Basing from other stackoverflow answer I found, I tried clearing the cache thinking that may be why nothing seems to change, but now the datepicker won't appear ^^;

**Server Side**
I use Laravel for backend, and this is the function that validates and stores user data inside my `RegistrationController.php`
*For now, I'm simply trying to get the function to work, before adding better validation rules*

```
public function store(){
        $validated = request()->validate([
            'date_of_birth' => ['required', 'dateformat:d/m/Y'],
            'gender' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'contact_number' => ['required', 'digits:11'],
            'password' => ['string',Password::min(8)],
        ]);

        $attributes = array_merge($validated, [
            'user_type_id' => 3,
        ]);

        $newUser = User::create($attributes);

        return redirect('/');

    }
```

The function works if I manually type the date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I tried adding a mutator to `User.php` model too but it doesn't seem to do anything

```
 public function setBirthDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the date format in the server side was what worked, by adding a mutator. I just set the mutator's name wrong. My column name was `date_of_birth`, but I set the mutator function's name to `setBirthDateAttribute($value)` when it should be
`setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)`.

Keep in mind Laravel's powerful name conventions fellow newbies! ^^;;;

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the "autoUpdateInput" while setting up [daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker), and no need to format by yourself.
Simply remove the `autoUpdateInput: false` and `$(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));`

```
 try {
        $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
        });

        var myCalendar = $('.js-datepicker');
        var isClick = 0;

        $(window).on('click',function(){
            isClick = 0;
        });

        $(myCalendar).on('apply.daterangepicker',function(ev, picker){
            isClick = 0;
        });

        $('.js-btn-calendar').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();

            if(isClick === 1) isClick = 0;
            else if(isClick === 0) isClick = 1;

            if (isClick === 1) {
                myCalendar.focus();
            }
        });

        $(myCalendar).on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            isClick = 1;
        });

        $('.daterangepicker').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });


    } catch(er) {console.log(er);}
```